# Issue Getting value with static and DOM

Tags: javascript, object

I have some issue trying to get values from my form by using classes and statics
.
I can get the ID by using UI.DOMstrings
and i can get the form's content by using

document.querySelector(UI.DOMstrings.title).value

But UI.getInput.title doesn't return anything.

Do you have any idea how I can fix it ? :)

```
class UI {

    static DOMstrings = {
        bookList: '#book-list',
        bookForm: '#book-form',
        title: '#title',
        author: '#author',
        isbn: '#isbn',
    };

    static getInput = {
        title: document.querySelector(UI.DOMstrings.title).value, // Will be either inc or exp
        author: document.querySelector(UI.DOMstrings.author).value,
        isbn: document.querySelector(UI.DOMstrings.isbn).value,

    };

};
```

EDIT:

```
  static getInput() {
        return {

            title: document.querySelector(UI.DOMstrings.title).value, // Will be either inc or exp
            author: document.querySelector(UI.DOMstrings.author).value,
            isbn: document.querySelector(UI.DOMstrings.isbn).value,

        }
    };
```

This way I can get the value by using UI.getInput().title but  it's a bit weird for me to use it this way.

I'm still looking to have something like that

```
UI.getInput().title
```

Answer (score 0):

You select element when the script just has been loaded, so result of querySelector can be empty

Try to call `querySelector` when you are sure that DOM has been built

Comment: How can i do that ? 
Because i'm launching this command with a submit event .

Comment: You can create an instance of the class when you click on submit: remove `static` keyword and call in as `const ui = new UI(); ui.getInput.title`